# Is Pre-Check offered by Spirit Airlines?

Tags: global-entry, tsa-precheck, spirit-airlines

Spirit [does not offer TSA Pre-Check](https://customersupport.spirit.com/hc/en-us/articles/203664053-Has-Spirit-partnered-with-TSA-to-allow-TSA-PreCheck-).

We have a Global Entry card.

Can we Pre-Check outside of the airline?

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No, not yet.  Their ops platform, Navitaire, just added support for PreCheck two months ago.  So far, Spirit has not enabled it.

PreCheck must be on the Boarding Pass you use to pass through TSA.  Just having Global Entry does not help with this scenario.

Answer (score 7):

Update: [Spirit joined TSA PreCheck in January 2017.](http://www.foxnews.com/travel/2017/01/27/spirit-joins-tsa-precheck-program.html)

Answer (score 3):

According to [the LA Times](http://www.latimes.com/business/la-fi-travel-briefcase-precheck-20160618-snap-story.html):

> Fla.-based Spirit Airlines is planning to join sometime this fall.

Your only option in the absence of your airline participating in PreCheck is to buy a fully refundable ticket on a participating airline, use that to pass security, and then refund it immediately after.

Comment: I doubt I'd do it unless I arrived at security and there were huge queues at regular security and precheck was empty and I was in danger of missing my flight. You could sort out the refund on the flight or even after landing possibly...

Comment: Note that refunding a ticket once you checked in would take more effort  comparing to usual refund; you'd have to call the airline, cancel the checkin and only then refund. Since time is an essence, you have to be on the ground until you ask for the refund and get confirmation, and the idea was to save time in security (thus spend less time at the airport), the risks are rather high.

Comment: I only offered the only option available if you're desparate to use precheck and your airline doesn't offer it. I'm not advocating that suggestion